# Is the tracing built in to ASP.Net Web Api 2 only meant for a non-production environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I read the [Global Error Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling) recommendations and the [Tracing in Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api) articles, and I understand how to set these things up. However, I noticed in the error handling part, that it states:

> While Web API does have tracing infrastructure that captures error conditions the tracing infrastructure is for diagnostics purposes and is not designed or suited for running in production environments. Global exception handling and logging should be services that can run during production and be plugged into existing monitoring solutions

I'm looking for clarification on this. Is this statement saying that errors should only be logged as part of the trace when not in production, or that a custom implementation of `ITraceWriter` should only be registered with the `HttpConfiguration` when not in production?

I would assume that the article says

> not designed or suited for running in production environments

simply for the performance impact, but is there some different contextual info that I could see for a specific error by looking at the `Exception` on the `TraceRecord` vs. the `Exception` that gets passed into the `IExceptionLogger`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by what was written, it's meant as a rudimentary form of tracing and logging that whilst fine for developer and diagnostic environments is not for production due to performance and feature reasons.

To be due-diligent it advises to use an out-of-process service (eg log4net in a separate process or take your pick from Azure) so as to reduce probability of logging failing due to a fault in the core process; room to expand performance; and potential for a more feature rich logging system not provided in the default design.

Comment: So, do people normally put debug compiler directives around registering the tracewriter, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: @CShark I don't know what the norm is for this case but not wanting to have two different systems for logging - one for DEV the other for PROD it makes more sense to pick one and use it across the board.  Knowing how popular log4net is globally, it makes for a good initial choice as your engine of choice

Comment: yeah, I'm not talking about the logging library, i would only be using log4net either way. I'm simply talking about putting compiler directives around this part: `config.Services.Replace(typeof(ITraceManager), new MyTraceManager());`

Comment: @CShark I already answered that.  Toss away their mechanism and use log4net right from the start.  There is no need for abstractions and using `#if` in code increases burden on testing because now there is different behaviours depending on how the program is compiled

Comment: This question is not about what logging framework to use. I already said I'm using log4net, but that's irrelevant to my question. I was asking about whether i should be registering my own `ITraceWriter` only in a dev environment. It seems you have answered that, so I'm sorry if I confused you with my comment.

Comment: @CShark I said _no_.  Don't use compiler directives.  Don't use `#if`.  Don't use `ITraceWriter` for reasons as given by Microsoft.  Don't do one thing for DEV and another for PROD

Comment: ...Microsoft already said don't use theirs for PROD so that imples `ITraceWriter ` too

Comment: For some background, there is some legacy code that right now that uses the `ITraceWriter` to log errors, so I was just trying to confirm my assumption that I should take that out and replace it with the `IExceptionLogger`, for the reasons we discussed above. Thanks for your help.